# Very low test accuracy with Cifar100

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, cifar100

```
def load_cifar100_data_test(datadir,test_bs):
    dl_obj = CIFAR100_truncated
    transform_test = _data_transforms_cifar100_test()   
    test_ds = dl_obj(datadir, classes=None, dataidxs=None, train=False, transform=transform_test, download=True)
    test_dl = data.DataLoader(dataset=test_ds, batch_size=test_bs, shuffle=False, drop_last=False)
    return test_dl
test_loader_global = load_cifar100_data_test(args.data_dir, args.batch_size)
```

I would like to know how can I plot a sample of image of this dataset to verify if it contains images or not, to know the reason of low test accuracy.